# Array not working correctly in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, chart.js

I'm doing a data integration project with my external ERP(Tally.ERP9) with PHP(version 7),JQuery and ChartJS. where I'm pulling data from Tally.ERP9 through ODBC and fetched the rows as array. I also converted PHP array Variable as JavaScript array Variable using the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test = '<?php 
    $stks = array_values($stocks);
    echo json_encode($stks);

 ?>';

var test2 = '<?php 
    $qtys = array_values($qty);
    $armap = array_map('intval', $qtys);
    echo json_encode($armap);

?>';</script>
```

Then I'm calling variable in JavaScript like below,

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var ctx = $("#pie-container").get(0).getContext("2d");

        alert(test);
        alert(test2);

        var data = {
      labels : test,
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fill: true,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        data: test2,
        spanGaps: false,
    }
]};
        var piechart = new Chart(ctx,{type:'line',data:data});
    });
```

while alerting its giving the desired array as Output, 
[image]
[image]
but when passing them as array to the chartJS, Its throwing the following error.
[image]
Please suggest me where I'm doing mistake. But I'm sure the chart.js is working with sample array that I made myself as hard coded. 
[image]

Please Guide me how to achieve the above chart by passing the array variable in Chartjs, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: try passing JSON.parse(test2) instead of test2 to the chartjs object

Comment: @naortor Wow Thanks, It solved my problem dude. Thanks a lot. but one more query what if I have some special character in my array. how can i eliminate them and pass it as string. can you help me.

Comment: try that - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19981380/4819077

Comment: Thanks Naortor, Will Check that out and let you know